# Values not being inserted into table

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to insert some values into a database, however, it's always unsuccessful and I'm not sure what the problem is. Could I get some assistance please

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO `incidenceoffire`(`locationOfFire`, `dateFireOccurred`, `timeFireOccurred`, `classOfFire`, `originOfFire`, `noOfWounded`, 
`noOfFatalities`,`occupancy`,`noOfFirePersonnelOnScene`,`noOfFireTrucks`,`backupUsed`)
VALUES('$locationoffire', '$datefireoccurred', '$timefireoccurred', '$classoffire', '$originoffire', '$occupancy', '$noofwounded', '$nooffatalities', 
'$noofpersonnel', '$nooftrucks', '$backuptrucks')";

    $incidenceoffire_id = mysql_insert_id();

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO `backuptrucks` (`unitName`) VALUES ('$unitname')";

    $query2 .=" WHERE `IncidenceOfFire_incidentID` = '".$incidenceoffire_id."'";

    $result = false;
    if(mysql_query('BEGIN')){

        if(mysql_query($query1) && mysql_query($query2))
        {
            $result = mysql_query('COMMIT');
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Insert Successful!");
                  </script>';
        }
        else
        {
            mysql_query('ROLLBACK');
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Insert Unsuccessful!");
                  </script>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: `mysql_insert_id()` - definition: *Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the **previous** query (usually INSERT).* Also **please** don't use MySQL as it is deprecated in 5.3+ and is removed in 5.5 currently. Please use [MySQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO - php data objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: so is it that i would have to somehow include the 'id'(which is auto_increment) in query1 before i can attempt to use mysql_insert_id()?

Comment: If the column is set to unique and is set to auto increment then you do not need to explicitly declare a value in your query. simply perform the query, then use `mysqli_insert_id();` to get the previous queries inserted ID

Comment: oh ok. I will start using mysqli then. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of clarity, here's what you need. I'm not going to optimize it or anything but it's a baseline for where you should start.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'name', 'user', 'database');

$query1 = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO 
             `incidenceoffire`(
                 `locationOfFire`, 
                 `dateFireOccurred`, 
                 `timeFireOccurred`, 
                 `classOfFire`, 
                 `originOfFire`, 
                 `noOfWounded`,                      
                 `noOfFatalities`,
                 `occupancy`,
                 `noOfFirePersonnelOnScene`,
                 `noOfFireTrucks`,
                 `backupUsed`
             )
             VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?));
```

In the above we're using mysqli's prepare. This function will allow us to safely escape the data that is being passed into the query. This is for security purposes. the `?` represents the value that we're inserting associated with the field's we've identified above.

```
$query1->bind_param('sssssssssss', 
             $locationoffire, 
             $datefireoccurred, 
             $timefireoccurred, 
             $classoffire, 
             $originoffire, 
             $occupancy, 
             $noofwounded, 
             $nooffatalities, 
             $noofpersonnel, 
             $nooftrucks, 
             $backuptrucks);
```

Here, we've used `bind_param` to bind the `variable` to the `?`'s that we've used in the prepared statement. This allows us to safely escape the data. the `s` in the first argument stands for `string` as the data we expect to receive from that variable should be a string. You can also use `i` for integer - when expecting only numbers, and `d` for double, if you expect to have `.`'s and `,`'s. Lastly, you can use `b` if you expect a blob to be transferred over time to the statement.

Now, because you have two statements, repeat the above and use `$query2`, then you can perform your conditional. We will use `execute()` to execute the prepared statement we built earlier.

```
if($query1->execute() &&  $query2->execute()):
    $result[] = $query1->commit();
    $result[] = $query2->commit();
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Insert Successful!");</script>';
else:
    $result[] = $query1->rollback();
    $result[] = $query2->rollback();
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Insert Unsuccessful!");</script>';
endif;
```

This should all function for you from the get go, but please read and understand what's being relayed. Always use documentation and examples provided at http://php.net, and please follow best practices for security less you create a site that becomes hacked and I end up repairing it one day